# Visual Studio 2015 - Class Wizard in C++

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

When I right click my project and go to Class Wizard I'm met with the following error:

"The solution's source code database may not have been opened. Please make sure the solution is not open in another copy of Visual Studio, and that its database file is not read only."

[image: VS Error Message]

What I've tried so far:

- Creating a new project
- Restarting Visual Studio
- Restarting PC
- Repairing Visual Studio
- Reinstalling Visual Studio
- Installing MS SQL Server Compact 3.5
- Deleting the folder: C:\Users\Jacob\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0

None of these have had any effect, and I'm finding very few pages online where others have had this issue. I am totally at a loss on what to do next.

If anyone has any ideas, I would really appreciate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem here was actually caused by JetBrains Resharper C++, which I didn't consider could be the problem.

There seems to be no solution, however the program provides an alternative Class Wizard in the same menu.

Comment: That is unlikely. ReSharper C++ does not provide its own Class Wizard, and can not really cause the original error since it does not use Visual Studio's source code database.